# Can I somehow allow an app to access all files?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I have some applications which I want to allow access to *not just for media folder*:

[image]

OS: Android12, OneUI4

Can I somehow gently ask the OS to provide **extra** permission to this application without modifying the application to request it explicitly?

I need the following permission for the above application:

[image]

Can I do this somehow?

Comment: As a user, you can only grant permissions the app itself requests. So you'd need to ask the corresponding developer for that.

Comment: And there's probably a reason why the dev can't implement it due to the [storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) and [the Play Store enforcement](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955).